# Error in switch(code, ic9 = { : EXPR must be a length 1 vector

Tags: r, shiny

Help me resolve this error:

```
Error in switch(code, ic9 = { : EXPR must be a length 1 vector
```

When I switch from one radio button to another, it should start displaying the result for the radio button selected and the result associated with it. Thats why I've used the switch case, but there is error in it.

CODE:

```
library(shiny)
library(RPostgreSQL)
shinyServer(function(input, output){
    # Return the requested dataset
    inputCode <- reactive({
                            input$code
                            code <<- {switch(input$code,
                                          i9= ic9,
                                          i10= ic10)}
                            input$icd
                                  })
    dbConn <- function(inputCode,out){
      con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("PostgreSQL"), user="postgres", password="xyz", dbname="ICD_9_10_Mapping", host = "localhost", port = 5432)
      on.exit(dbDisconnect(con), add=TRUE)
      query1 <- "SELECT icd_10_codes, description, flags FROM icd_9_10_dia WHERE icd_9_codes ='"
      query2 <- "SELECT icd_9_codes, description, flags FROM icd_10_9_dia WHERE icd_10_codes ='"
      switch(code,
             ic9 = {X <<- query1},
             ic10 = {X <<- query2})
      invert <- "'"
        stmt <- paste(X,toString(input$icd, width = 10),invert, sep = "")
        res <- dbSendQuery(con, statement = stmt)
        out <<- fetch(res, n = -1)
    }
      output$out1 <- renderTable(dbConn(inputCode,out))})
```

Comment: You are assigning the global variable `code` from inside a reactive expression; that's almost always an indication that you're on the wrong track. Reactive expressions (i.e. `reactive({...})`) should only be used for calculating values, not side effects.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify this a bit just use your input$code directly with if statements rather than switch. For example:

```
if(input$code == 'ic9') {
query <- "SELECT icd_10_codes, description, flags FROM icd_9_10_dia WHERE icd_9_codes ='"
} else {
query <- "SELECT icd_9_codes, description, flags FROM icd_10_9_dia WHERE icd_10_codes ='"
}
```

You can use input$code in your function or put it in your call to dbConn (i.e., dbConn(input$code) ). I don't see where 'out' is coming from. It is defined in dbConn but you are using it in a call to dbConn which will not work. Also, the call to the reactive should be inputCode() but with the if statements suggested above you wouldn't need it.